# How to make Webview Working in Kiosk Self Service

Tags: android, webview

i have a problem i had already deploy system aplication apk, app running well and i tried to running aplication apk to another phone i don't have any issues but after i tried to running apk in Kiosk Self service App running but webview not working showing white screen can someone help me to fix this thanks in advance

#Updated Spesification
Phone :
OS Android SDK 23 Android 6.0 model Vivo 1601
OS Android SDK 24 Android 7.0 model Samsung A5
//other phone working well not problem but after installed in kiosk self service webview app not working

Comment: You should [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64998036/edit) your question with make/model of device along with what version of OS. You should also mention how you test (model of phone & OS).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for you'r suggestion, i really don't get it why webview cannot running in kiosk self service

Comment: Please clean up your question with what does work and what doesn't. I would double check on each device what version of System WebView / Chrome Browser is being run. If a basic 'Hello World in html/javascript' in WebView runs on both, leaning toward some incompatibility with WebView. You can try to diagnose with [Remote Debugging WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank's for you'r answer, i will try to using remote debugging i'm really confuse because running on android mobile device but cannot running in kiosk self service android